# Python how to Read last modified date of file from TeamSites

Tags: python, pandas, sharepoint

I am using Shuttle package to read and write excel files to TeamSites.below is the same code:

### Read the file from Teamsites

```
from shuttle import sharepoint, rfs


with rfs.open(TS, 'Reports/Weekly/Python_Datasets/fcs.csv','r') as remote_file:
fcs1=pd.read_csv(remote_file)
```

how do i read the last modified date and time of same file from Teamsites.

### Tired as below and got error:

```
from shuttle import sharepoint, rfs

with rfs.open(TS, 'Reports/Weekly/Python_Datasets/fcs.csv','r') as remote_file:
fcs1=os.path.getmtime(remote_file)
```

#### Error:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i found the answer to my question. Hope it will help others:

Shuttle has function List which will print all metadata info for the file
Below is the syntax i used:

```
dt1=TS.list('Reports/Monitoring/Forecast/file.csv')
```

This is in list format, convert it to json and read json

```
dt1=pd.read_json(json.dumps(dt1)).TimeLastModified
```

this gives  the last moffied timestamp for file on sharepoint/Teamsites.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You got a file-like object from `rfs.open(xxx)` which is not a string or buffer needed by `getmtime`.

See https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime .

Comment: Ok, how do I pass path using rfs?

Comment: `os.path.getmtime("Reports/Weekly/Python_Datasets/fcs.csv")`